# Llamada recursiva al destructor agota el stack

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy intentando hacer el destructor de la lista enlazada para que se libera la memoria que he reservado con new. Sin embargo, cuando llamo al destructor implícitamente usando delete, solo me aparece el mensaje del cout que tengo en el destructor, por lo que entiendo que se está llamando recursivamente. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?
Aquí está el código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Link {
public:
    std::string value;
    ~Link()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor\n";
        Link *head = this;
        while (head)
        {
            Link *tmp = head;
            head = head->prev;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
    Link(std::string v, Link* p = 0, Link* s = 0)
        : value(v), prev(p), succ(s) { }

    Link* insert(Link* n);                     
    Link* next() const { return succ; }
    Link* previous() const { return prev; }
private:
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
};

Link* Link::insert(Link* n) {
    if (n==0) return this;
    n->succ = this;
    if (prev) prev->succ = n;
    n->prev = prev;
    prev = n;
    return n;
}

void print_all(const Link* p)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    while (p) {
        cout << p->value;
        if ((p=p->next())) cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << " }";
}

int main() {

    Link* norse_gods = new Link("Thor");
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link("Odin"));
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link("Zeus"));
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link("Freia"));

    print_all(norse_gods);
    delete norse_gods;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El destructor que has implementado está, directamente, mal:

```
~Link()
{
    std::cout << "destructor\n";
    Link *head = this;
    while (head) // <<--- por esto
    {
        Link *tmp = head;
        head = head->prev;
        delete tmp; // <--- por esto
    }
}
```

Para entender el problema imaginemos una lista con 3 elementos:

```
A -> B -> C
```

Si hacemos `delete A` la secuencia que se produce es la siguiente:

```
delete A
delete A
delete A
delete A
...
```

Como no llegas a salir del destructor en ningún momento la memoria no se termina de liberar y por eso no recibes un error por doble borrado.

Este bucle tan curioso lo tenemos aquí (he eliminado el código sobrante):

```
~Link()
{
  Link* head = this; // head = this
  Link* tmp = head;  // tmp  = this
  delete tmp;        // delete this
}
```

Vamos, que estás borrando cosas sin control.

Por otro lado, verás que te he marcado también el `while`. El motivo es que, suponiendo que el destructor no intentase borrar el propio objeto, provocarías dobles borrados:

```
delete A
    delete B
        delete C
    delete C // << --- ups
```

El incremento de tabulacion indica llamadas recursivas. Así, `delete A` invocaría a `delete B` y a `delete C`... pero al borrarse `B` se invocaría `delete C`... estaríamos intentando borrar dos veces `C` y ahí el sistema operativo se va a quejar y con razón... el segundo delete intentaría liberar una región de memoria que no tienes asignada y el sistema operativo matará el proceso para evitar que corrompa memoria que no le pertenece.

Un nodo únicamente tendría que preocuparse de borrar al siguiente nodo... este siguiente nodo se encargará de borrar al que le sigue y así hasta llegar al final:

```
~Link()
{
    std::cout << "destructor\n";
    delete succ;
}
```

Otro error que estás cometiendo, y esta vez de arquitectura, es tratar un nodo a su vez como una lista. La solución quedaría más elegante y legible si tienes una clase que se encargue de gestionar los nodos (una clase lista):

```
class Link
{
public:
    Link(std::string v, Link * p = nullptr, Link * s = nullptr);

    ~Link() { delete succ; }

    Link* next() const { return succ; }
    Link* previous() const { return prev; }

private:
    std::string value;
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
}; 

class List
{
public:
    ~List()
    {
      delete first;
    }

    Link* insert(int index);

private: 

    Link * first = nullptr;
};
```

> Pero la lista la estás eliminando recursivamente. En una lista muy grande esto es un problema.

Bueno, si tienes que lidiar con listas demasiado grandes entonces razón de más para contar con una clase Lista:

```
~Link(){ std::cout << "destructor " << value << '\n'; }

~List()
{
  Link * node = first;
  while( node )
  {
    Link * tmp = node->succ;
    delete node;
    node = tmp;
  }
}
```

Nota que ahora es `List` la que borra los objetos. Ya no hay llamadas recursivas ni dobles borrados.

Comment: Pero la lista la estás eliminando recursivamente. En una lista muy grande esto es un problema.

Comment: @Aprendiz06 ya he respondido a tu comentario